# no-unused-vars throwing Error rather than Warning?

Tags: webpack, eslint, babel-eslint

We recently updated several NPM packages and other parts of our React application, and now `no-unused-vars` is throwing an error rather than a warning.

[image]

One of the updates to our application was updating from `babel-eslist` to `@babel/eslint-parser` in our package.json (now have `"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2"`), and updating the parser in our `.eslintrc` accordingly.

```
// "parser": "babel-eslint", // 
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
```

Another potentially-relevant update is that we updated `react-scripts` to the latest version `"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"`. Is it possible to have `no-unused-vars` return warnings again, rather than errors?

We have the following rule for `no-unused-vars`

```
"rules": {
  ...
  "no-unused-vars": 2, // disallow declaration of variables that are not used in the code
```

Comment: Did you try configuring this like any other ESLint rule? What _else_ is in your `.eslintrc`?

Comment: We did not make any other changes to our `.eslintrc` other than changing the parser after installing @babel/eslint-parser. Perhaps a rule needs to be added?

Comment: If you're not happy with your current ESLint configuration, changing it is probably worth a try at least!

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Zero'ing in on our eslist file. I just updated the question with our eslint rule for this. We haven't changed our eslist rule for `no-unused-vars` so confused why it is now throwing an error rather than a warning.

Comment: `2` is explicitly the error level (I'd recommend using the string rather than number option to make this more obvious, see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#configuring-rules). I don't know why you were only getting warnings before.

Comment: We were using `babel-eslist` before rather than `@babel/eslint-parser`, perhaps the numbers correspond with different levels?

Comment: Changing the parser (not even changing, really, just a newer version of the same one) wouldn't change any of the configuration of the rules. You _explicitly_ had it at error, as far as what you've shown us says.